# systemd service in pacemaker for high availability

Tags: linux, systemd, high-availability, pacemaker, systemctl

I came to know about the pacemaker for high availability.
I have one simple service running on linux VM. 
I have started that using `systemctl start <service name>` command.  I want to make this HA in case my linux host goes down.

For that purpose, I have setup another linux host and enabled the service.
On this linux host, service can be started manually using `systemctl start <service name>` command.

I have installed pacemaker with corosync and created the cluster. In `pcs resource list`, it shows my service along with others as `systemd:<service name>`.

I have created a resource using command

```
pcs resource create my-resource systemd:<service_name>
```

Resource got created successully and it is `started` mode also.
To test, I shutdown the first host, I am expecting that service should come up on other host as it already setup there.

But it is not coming up on second host.

`pcs status` output show shutdowned host as offline.

I don't need any virtual IP here as my service quite simple which pulls the data from source process it.

Is there other configuration needed to achieve the service HA.?

Comment: can you share your full PCS configuration? `pcs config show`